# I am not getting the output i desire

Tags: c, io, operators

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a, b;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter another number: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    int add = a+b;
    printf("a + b = %d", add);
    return 0;
}
```

**Above is the *C* code, that uses operators.**

> I use a ***TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit*** compiler.

whenever i run the above program, i get the following output:

```
Enter a number:
4

--------------------------------
Process exited after 16.11 seconds with return value 3221225477
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**It's not allowing me to neither enter any other number nor it's displaying any prompt**
I desire this output:

```
Enter a number:
4
Enter another number:
2
a + b = 6

--------------------------------
Process exited after <seconds> seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Is it the compiler's problem or is it an error in the code?

Comment: is the explanation for the problem correct? or should i add any more info?

Comment: try building with `-Wall -Wextra`; for `scanf()` need to pass references to vars `a` and `b`

Comment: What is ```-Wall -Wextra``` and how do i build with it ?

Comment: I sorted all the errors out and edited some parts of the code. It's working perfectly working fine now!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter another number: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    int add = a+b;
    printf("a + b = %d \n", add);
    return 0;
}
```